# Windows Phone 7 GWT Phonegap smalle size

Tags: windows-phone-7, gwt, cordova

I am trying to write a phonegap app with GWT for windows phone 7. I have the following in my module.

```
RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get("wrapper");
    AbsolutePanel ap = new AbsolutePanel();
    rootPanel.add(ap);
    ap.setSize("480px", "800px");
```

I add my components in the AbsolutePanel. And in my css I have the following.

```
#wrapper{
    width:480px;
    height:800px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#FF0000;
}
```

When I compile this and put it on the Windows Phone it is *really* small compared to what it is on my desktop. Is there some setting I should be using to make it 480*800? Also the images do not seem to be showing, but they do show in my desktop app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likley that you're not setting the ViewPort for the page.
By default it's set to around 2000. (I can't remember the exact value off the top of my head.)

Try something like:

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,height=device-height' />
```

Comment: No Luck. Would my setting the width and height is css have something to do with it?

Comment: I removed the absolute panel, and that seems to have worked out alright. Thanks